# LinkedIn Job Search REST API Issue(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, linkedin-api

I see there has been questions similar to this but the responses to them explains my asking a similar question here. I am wanting to utilize LinkedIn's REST API for my personal job hunt, specifically utilizing the job search API capabilities.

My problem comes in with retrieving an access token and autorisation to actually use the app. I have tried the below code - the first cell is to retrieve autorisation and the second is to retrieve an access token:

```
from linkedin import linkedin

APPLICATON_KEY = 'XXXXXX'
APPLICATON_SECRET = 'XXXXX'

RETURN_URL = 'http://localhost:8000'
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(APPLICATON_KEY, APPLICATON_SECRET, RETURN_URL, 
linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values())
print (authentication.authorization_url)  #open this url on your browser
```

Access token:

```
authentication = linkedin.LinkedInAuthentication(
                APPLICATON_KEY,
                APPLICATON_SECRET,
                RETURN_URL,
                linkedin.PERMISSIONS.enums.values()
            )

authentication.authorization_code = '#############################################'
result = authentication.get_access_token()

print ("Access Token:", result.access_token)
print ("Expires in (seconds):", result.expires_in)
```

When I attempt to retreieve authorisation (required for access token) the following error occurs:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/linkedin/linkedin.py", line 294
    except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError), error:
                                                         ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It's an obvious syntax error, however am ignorant to what it is exactly - I have a feeling it might be my localhost

Answer (score 1):

That error points to the comma separating the exception classes from the variable name.

A comma there is Python 2.x syntax, so that means the `linkedin` library you're using is not compatible with Python 3.

If you're using [this library](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin), you can see it's not been updated in 5 years. [This](https://github.com/HootsuiteLabs/python-linkedin-v2) ([PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/python-linkedin-v2/)) seems like a slightly fresher fork.

Comment: Yes, used the first linked library. Thanks, will give the other a bash and let you know

Comment: Only problem with the linked libraries is they do not support job search capabilities - seems to only support profile and connections capabilities